# Define Typescript return type & props

Tags: typescript

What would be correct typescript syntax to return a type from a function, while also defining the props that it accepts?

```
interface Item {
  [key: string]: {
    value: number;
  };
}

const items: Item = {
 foo: {
   value: 1
 }
}

interface ItemsGetterProps {
  something: boolean
}

const getItems: ({ something }: ItemsGetterProps) => Item => some_function(items, something) // returns Item
```

Comment: Does this help? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Comment: No, not a single example with proper ES6 arrow function, everywhere it example ES5 functions are being used

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a type from a function, but this is what I presume you mean:

```
const getItems: ((props: ItemsGetterProps) => Items) = ({ something }) => {
    return some_function(items, something);
}
```

or

```
const getItems: ((props: ItemsGetterProps) => Items) = ({ something }) => some_function(items, something);
```